# How to Save file as mp4 in mediaRecorder or convert Blob to mp4

Tags: node.js, angular12

I am recording a video in the frontend(Angular 12) using 'mediaRecorder'. Once i click on the stop button i am calling the below function. Here, I am getting a Blob file, but i want to get a mp4 file or when i send this blob file to my backend (Nodejs 14). I want to convert the Blob to mp4. I have tried different options for converting blob to mp4 at the backend but nothing works. therefore please help me to convert this blob file to mp4 or help me to save this file in mp4 instead of Blob.

```
 this.mediaRecorder.onstop = (event: Event) => {
    const videoBuffer = new Blob(this.recordedBlobs, {
      type: 'video/mp4'
    });
    this.downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBuffer);  
    this.recordVideoElement.src = this.downloadUrl;
    console.log('this.downloadUrl '+this.downloadUrl );
    this.saveLiveVideo();//sending file to backend
  };
```

Comment: hi, did you find some solution?